# Using matplotlib to plot text

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to put text in a graph, but for some reason I can't do it using `plt.text`. I get the

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list ("not float") to list
```

I don't really know what to change to get this working.

```
x = [3, 1, 4, 5, 1]
y = [5, 4, 4, 3, 7]

fig=plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.xlim(0.5, 7)
plt.ylim(0, 7.5)

ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')

ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

plt.scatter(x, y, marker="x", color="red")

Names=['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name4']

plt.text(x + 0.1, y + 0.1, Names, fontsize=9)
```

Comment: The error is not with `text`, it's with `x+0.1` and `y+0.1`, which you would be more aware of if you processed and posted the whole error

Comment: The error was with trying to use all Names at once in `plt.text` and adding 0.1 to x and y which are of type `list`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `plt.text` in a vectorised manner. It won't work that way. You were also adding `0.1` (a float) to `x` (a list) and hence the self-explanatory error.  You have to loop over your `Names` and use the corresponding `x` and `y` value and put the `text` one name at a time. You can do it using `enumerate` as follows

```
Names=['name1', 'name2','name3','name4','name4']
for i, name in enumerate(Names):
    plt.text(x[i]+0.1, y[i]+0.1, name, fontsize=9)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code.

The one that is raising is that you attempt to add a scalar to a Python list: `x + 0.1` and `y + 0.1`. `+` is defined as concatenation, which is what the error is telling you. You can potentially fix this by converting `x` and `y` to numpy arrays ahead of time. For arrays, `+` is defined as element-wise addition, as you were expecting. However, this won't solve your second problem.

The documentation for [`pyplot.text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) explicitly states that the `x` and `y` inputs are scalars: you can only plot one string per call. That means you need a loop:

```
for x_, y_, name in zip(x, y, Names):
    plt.text(x_ + 0.1, y_ + 0.1, name, fontsize=9)
```

Please read your errors carefully and post the whole thing next time.

Comment: Perhaps you should add `+0.1` to x_ and y_ to avoid the text overlapping the markers