# Calculate 6 hour mean values of a column in a pandas dataframe, plot values as text over graph

Tags: python, pandas, date, plot, mean

I have create a basic pandas dataframe in python that has multiple columns. The first column I have created is a timestamp from multiple columns that included date time info. The other columns are just data for each corresponding time.

I want to get the mean of these values every 6 hours and then plot the values as text within the line graph that I have created with the other data, but at the top of the graph plot (so within the lines).

I have tried multiple ways, I just can't seem to figure out how to get a 6 hour mean from a column, much less get to the step to plot the values.

To be specific, I just need the 6 hour mean of 2 of the columns, the two I use for the line graph. For the solution, in this case, it doesn't matter which one.

Just in case it's necessary. The following is the code used to create the datetime column.

```
#convert first time columns into one datetime column
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second']])
```

The data looks like this for example:

```
267 2019-02-08 15:25:23  12.2  19.2  20.6  ...   22.4  
268 2019-02-08 15:52:48  11.7  16.8  17.8  ...   19.2  
269 2019-02-08 16:29:23  12.0  15.6  16.2  ...   17.0  
270 2019-02-08 16:47:41  11.9  15.6  16.1  ...   16.7  
271 2019-02-08 17:33:23  11.1  15.2  15.9  ...   16.7  
272 2019-02-08 17:51:39  10.8  15.0  15.7  ...   16.5  
273 2019-02-08 18:28:14  10.7  14.3  14.9  ...   15.8  
274 2019-02-08 18:46:31  10.8  14.2  14.7  ...   15.4  
275 2019-02-08 19:32:13  10.8  12.1  12.6  ...   13.1  
276 2019-02-08 19:50:33  10.1  11.8  12.3  ...   12.9  
277 2019-02-08 20:18:01   8.6  10.6  11.1  ...   11.8  
278 2019-02-08 20:44:24   8.3  10.5  11.1  ...   12.0  
279 2019-02-08 21:30:08   9.1  10.4  11.1  ...   12.3  
280 2019-02-08 21:48:26   9.0  10.4  11.2  ...   12.4  
281 2019-02-08 22:34:11   9.2  11.5  12.4  ...   13.4  
282 2019-02-08 22:52:30   8.6  12.5  13.4  ...   14.3  
283 2019-02-08 23:29:05   8.8  12.6  13.2  ...   14.2  
284 2019-02-08 23:47:23   9.3  12.2  12.8  ...   13.7  
285 2019-02-09 00:33:07   9.1  10.3  11.3  ...   12.5  
286 2019-02-09 00:51:23   7.8   8.5   9.5  ...   10.9  
287 2019-02-09 01:28:10   0.8   1.2   1.9  ...    3.0   
288 2019-02-09 01:46:50   0.6   1.2   1.9  ...    3.1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which columns are you interested in calculating the mean for? You don't provide any information about the line plot that you are referring to.

Comment: For the 6 hours average have a look at pd.rolling regarding the plot check plotly or bokeh.

Comment: For the sake of the solution, I only need two of the columns, it can be any 2. I only use two in the line graph but the dataframe is very large so I didn't post the specific ones. The numbers are close to the same throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the 6h mean like so:

```py
df.set_index('datetime').resample('6h').mean()
```

That's one value every 6 hours. If you want a rolling mean, you'll want to check out `pd.DataFrame.rolling`.

[Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497197/using-matplotlib-to-plot-text) that talks about plotting text, if you're using `matplotlib` or a package based on it like `seaborn`. You can use the date as the x coordinate and some maximum value as your y coordinate. If you're already using something else, you'll have to be more specific in your question.

Comment: This worked, I had worked with resample before, but never tried set_index.